# How to configure Nginx for different subdomains via different ports?

Tags: nginx

I've struggled for couple of weeks on this configuration.What I want to achieve can be listed as follows.

1.I registered a domain not long ago.And I've set up some web service on my VPS,such as a blog,a forum and Owncloud. Now I want to configured the Nginx so that I can run all the service on one VPS and one IP address. In order to run owncloud,I have to modify the `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`to `listen = 9000`.In this case,I can only get one service (Owncloud)function,because if I want to run the forum I must uncomment the `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.What's more,I've tried to uncomment both of them,Nginx showed 502 afterwards.

2.I'm using Hexo as my blog.When I start the server,I can access into my blog on IP:4000.So I wonder if I could run my blog server on background and edit the posts online via a subdomain which has been redirected to port 4000.If it's possible,should I modify the `nginx.conf` or add something in `sites-available`?

3.Can I deploy different web services on different subdomain?Which file is to modify?It's said that I can achieve this by using reverse proxy?

Sorry for the pathetic English and expression.Thanks in advance.

Comment: All problem solved.
1.I changed both config files of them to `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`
2.Reverse -proxying was established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going at it point by point:

1. The advantage of PHP-FPM, which you are using, is that you can have multiple **separate** interpreters running in your pool. To do so, simply copy the file at */etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf* to somewhere else, say */etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/forum.conf*, change the `listen` directive, and you've got a second php interpreter running, entirely separate from the first one. That way owncloud (www) and your forum (forum) have their own distinct php.
2. This is called reverse-proxying. nginx does that well. You simply add a new site definition in *sites-available* that does reverse-proxying to port `4000` on your server, then symlink (or copy) that site definition to *sites-enabled* and restart nginx. You will have to setup Hexo to start automatically for that to work.
3. You can deploy different web services on different subdomains. As long as the dns is configured to point that name to your server, you can configure the server to respond differently for every subdomain using site definitions. You need to modify the files in *sites-enabled* to determine which names nginx knows how to respond to.

Comment: Firstly thanks for responding.And do you get any idea of changing the ssl port?My 443 port is already taken by another process which cannot be changed.Besides do you mean I can just simply add some rules in the config files like `proxy_pass IP address:4000` as a reverse-proxying?

Comment: For the ssl port you just need to change the nginx `listen` directive to listen on a different port. And you are correct for the reverse-proxy config. You might have to add a new site definition or a new location block, but that's essentially it.

Comment: Well,as you said,I copied the `www.conf`to`owncloud.conf`and restart both nginx and php5-fpm,but it did not work and the error log showed `111 Connection refused`.That two config files are using the same 80 port.